# Sitecore URL Agent SSL Exception hosted in Azure Website

Tags: azure

We have hosted our sitecore CMS on to azure web apps. The HTTP is disabled on NSG layer, so only HTTPs is allowed.

We use azure provided certificate (i.e. azurewebsite wild card cert.) Noticed that URL agent isn't working with SSL. Read few posts below but didn't help:
https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/8/t/3984

Below is the exception that's been logged.

> ManagedPoolThread #6 00:13:05 INFO  Job started:
>   Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent ManagedPoolThread #6 00:13:05 INFO 
>   Scheduling.UrlAgent started. Url:
>   https://cms.myasite.azurewebsite.com/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx
>   ManagedPoolThread #6 00:13:05 ERROR Exception in UrlAgent (url:
>   https://cms.myasite.azurewebsite.com/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx)
>   Exception: System.Net.WebException Message: The underlying connection
>   was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. Source: System
>   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest&
>   request)    at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData(Uri address)    at
>   Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.ExecuteWebPage(String url, NameValueCollection
>   headers)    at Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent.Run()
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.IO.IOException Message: Unable to read data from the
>   transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by
>   the remote host. Source: System    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)    at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 count)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
>   Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)    at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
>   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
>
> Nested Exception
>
> Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException Message: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host Source: System    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, SocketFlags socketFlags)    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size)

It looks related to azure certificate but not having any luck on how to resolve. Buying a proper certificate is not an option as we have no plan to setup custom domain for CMS.

Any suggestions will be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok managed to solve this issue by adding this line as part of application startup:

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

More detail on this issue is here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28286086/default-securityprotocol-in-net-4-5